# Creating custom groups within the ribbon in Mac Powerpoint 2011

Tags: mac, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2011

It seems like I can only adjust whether tabs are shown or hidden and the order in which the tabs appear.

Am I missing something? or does powerpoint's mac version just suck?

Answer (score 0):

The latter.  The Mac version doesn't allow for ribbon customization.